# PowerShell file upload to S3 using securestring credentials

Tags: amazon-s3, powershell-2.0

I am trying to upload a document via PowerShell script. I have created a secure string password file using the following command:

```bsh
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File c:\filename.txt
```

This stores my secret key needed to access the S3 bucket to upload the needed file.  From all the Internet searching I have done this is typically used to inject credentials to login to a Windows prompt or O365 prompt.

I then use the following command to bring it back into the script:

```bsh
$pass = Get-Content "C:\filename.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

Basically what I am looking for here it to not pass another variable that will also decrypt the password as many have said on some of my finds on the Internet. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: "A better way" to do what? What problem are you trying to solve here? What is not working the way you expected?

Comment: I need to use a IAM Key that acts as the "user" and a secret key that is the "password" to upload a file i generate through PowerShell. Then I want to dump that file into a S3 bucket. This whole thing works if I put these keys as plain text in the script, but I do not want these keys to be plain text in these scripts. I want to somehow do this somewhat secure.

Comment: If you need the password/token as plaintext you need the password/token as plaintext. No way around that.